# How to pass dynamic parameters in a method call

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

I am using dapper for getting data from the database and since database connections need to be disposed I put it in a using block. But I started to notice I saw a lot of the same usings and I thought it might be smart to write a wrapper function, something like this:

```
    protected IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string query, dynamic param = null)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeString"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            return connection.Query<T>(query, param);
        }
    }
```

But this won't compile and I don't quite understand the error I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' has no applicable method named
>   'Query' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting
>   the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the
>   extension method syntax

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to pass dynamic parameters the way I am trying here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `object` instead of `dynamic`.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string query, object param) 
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeString"].ConnectionString;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
    {
        return connection.Query<T>(query, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cornelis no problem, enjoy using dapper :)